# backuppc not keeping backup history

Tags: rsync, windows-server-2003-r2, backuppc

We have backuppc backing up a number of computers on our network. One particular Windows 2003 server has a problem. Backuppc performs a backup twice a day using rsyncd just as set up, but keeps no history of backups. The backup number always remains the same. It used to work a few months ago so I have one backup number at June 29 and the next one at September 11. As far as I know no configurations have changed. I don't see any errors in the logs that would relate to this. I've googled and searched sourceforge, stackexchange, etc but as far as I have been able to find nobody else seems to have this problem. How can I get this server to to keep historical backups?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was an empty RsyncShareName and BackupZeroFilesIsFatal. I had one share name set up that did not have any content any more. This seemed to keep the backup from completing successfully. Deleting that share from the server's config fixed the problem.